Looking for a loop using tesseract to convert images to text
The code to convert 1 image is:
import pytesseract
import PIL.Image
import cv2
myconfig = r"--psm 6 --oem 3"
text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(PIL.Image.open('book/page1.jpg'), config=myconfig)
print(text1)
tried to make a loop with for but didn't get it
